# ASP.NET: What is DataReader return type if my sql data type is float?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, string, datareader

My SQL data of column Price is of type float.
When I use `DataReader` to read in a row and try to access the column value as

```
reader["Price"]
```

I got a compiler error: "The best overloaded method match for `decimal.Parse(string)` has some invalid arguments."

I want assign this value to a decimal variable, how do I do so?
I got the compiler error above when I tried:

```
decimal price;
price = decimal.Parse(reader["Price"]);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The return type for `reader["Price"]` is  `object`.  To do what you're trying to do use this:

```
price = decimal.Parse(reader["Price"].ToString());
```

However, if there's the slightest change you can end up with a string that cannot be converted to a Decimal consider using the [Decimal.TryParse Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.tryparse.aspx) which will allow you to determine if the conversion was successful.

**EDIT**
The SqlDataReader has a number of different *GetXXX* methods that allow you to retrieve typed data from a column in a DataReader without first having to cast to/from an intermediate type.  I originally advised you to use `SqlDataReader.GetDecimal` because I saw the type you wanted to retrieve is a decimal.  I see now that the SQL data type of the this data is actually float so I was going to advise that you use `SqlDataReader.GetFloat`.  I tested this though and got an invalid cast exception.  The reason for this is that the SQL float is not compatible with the .NET float data type.

So I checked table in [SQL Server Data Types and Their .NET Framework Equivalents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) on MSDN and found that the SQL float is the equivalent to the .NET double. I tried `SqlDataReader.GetDouble` and was able to retrieve data without error.   Since you want a decimal though, you'll need to cast:

```
price = (decimal)reader.GetDouble(reader.GetOrdinal("Price"));
```

Comment: Thanks so much. But if I use the GetDecimal method, I have to use an integer to access the column such as reader.GetDecimal(2). I can't use reader.GetDecimal("Price"). Am I wrong? I am new to this programming business. Thanks.

Comment: @user776676 The int argument for GetDecimal indicates the column position within the DataReader from which to get the data.  To refer to this column position by column name (improving readability of your code, BTW), use the DataReader's GetOrdinal method and pass it the name of your column.  I updated my answer because I steered ya wrong with my GetDecimal advice (I also show using the GetOrdinal method.

Answer (score 3):

`decimal.Parse` expects `string` as a parameter. It parses `decimal` out of `string`.

`reader["Price"]` is object, while the real type underneath this object will be `float`.

The reason why it fail is because it cannot cast object to string.

So you could do

```
var price = Convert.ToDecimal(reader["Price"]);
```

or

```
var price = (float)reader["Price"];
```

if you know for sure that you type is `float`.

Answer (score 1):

An SQL Float is a Double in C#. Check out the documentation. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx

Comment: Koen's answer made it clear. Here is how I use it:                float x = (float)reader.GetDouble(0)